# Windows Server 2008 built in back up issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup

On our windows 2008 r2 server, I was trying to configure back of server, but I am continue to get error message saying one of the volumes is fat32 and all the volumes needs to be ntfs. After searching online  I found that the issue happens with dell server, for some reason it creates boot volume fat32. The other forums are suggesting to use convert.exe to convert the volume from fat32 to ntfs.

I want to know is it safe to use convert.exe on production server? and are there any other options?

Thanks for all your help

Comment: what volume is fat32 do you have real data on it? or is the dell utilities volume or something like it?

Comment: More than likely it is the diagnostic partition and can be excluded from the backup.  Right click the drive in question and select properties, the Filesystem type will be shown on the first tab.

Comment: I think they are windows boot files, The content is as follow folder Boot and files Recycle.bin,bootmgr,bootsect.bak

Comment: could be a bootable repair volume, is there a windows directory? run cmd elevated then do the following. and post the result "wmic logicaldisk get filesystem,name,volumename"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input guys,

I ran the convert.exe command and it converted the file system to NTFS form fat32 pretty quick and I restarted the server. Everything seems to be working well.